# how to get field type in forms.py (not in template) Django

Tags: python, django

I want to get a specific field type in the `forms.py`, so I can add to that fields group a specific CSS class.

In my `models.py` I have multiple CharField, DateField and others like BigIntegerField, etc., and I want to ask for that. Here's my code:

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            if type(field) == CharField: #Here's the problem
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                    'class': 'form-control'})

    class Meta:
        model   = MyModel
        fields  = '__all__'
```

I can't do it one by one because I have many fields in my model. Any ideas how can I do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don’t you want to set the class on the template? If you are trying to use bootstrap on all your form fields, I’d recommend using [django-bootstrap4](http://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)

Comment: @CarlBrubaker I tried to do something like that how it is described at [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html), accessing the  form fields individually and it was useful for me but there were some things that I couldn't understand. I didn't know about django-bootstrap4, It looks llike a good alternative, maybe for my future projects, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will return the string of what `Field` used:

```
YourModel._meta.get_field('field_name').get_internal_type()
```

This will return the class

```
YourModel._meta.get_field('field_name')
>>> # Output .....
```

in your case:

```
if YourModel._meta.get_field(field).get_internal_type() == 'CharField':
    self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'})
```

Comment: Thanks @Lemayzeur, that was what I needed, it works perfect!

Comment: glad to be of help!